# Reading assembly code

Tags: assembly, binary

I am trying to decipher what this assembly code does. I know it reads in six integers to unlock the next level.

```
   0x08048c24 <+0>:     push   %esi
   0x08048c25 <+1>:     push   %ebx
   0x08048c26 <+2>:     sub    $0x34,%esp
```

I think these first three lines are just initalizing stuff.

```
   0x08048c29 <+5>:     lea    0x18(%esp),%eax
   0x08048c2d <+9>:     mov    %eax,0x4(%esp)
   0x08048c31 <+13>:    mov    0x40(%esp),%eax
   0x08048c35 <+17>:    mov    %eax,(%esp)
   0x08048c38 <+20>:    call   0x80493b4 <read_six_numbers>
   0x08048c3d <+25>:    cmpl   $0x0,0x18(%esp)
   0x08048c42 <+30>:    jne    0x8048c4b <phase_2+39>
   0x08048c44 <+32>:    cmpl   $0x1,0x1c(%esp)
   0x08048c49 <+37>:    je     0x8048c6a <phase_2+70>
```

I think this compares if the first number and first input are equal, and if not, jump to the explode_bomb function on +39. Then it compares the next input number with the second number and if they are equal (match), then skip passed the explode_bomb function.

```
   0x08048c4b <+39>:    call   0x8049375 <explode_bomb>
   0x08048c50 <+44>:    jmp    0x8048c6a <phase_2+70>
   0x08048c52 <+46>:    mov    -0x8(%ebx),%eax
   0x08048c55 <+49>:    add    -0x4(%ebx),%eax
   0x08048c58 <+52>:    cmp    %eax,(%ebx)
   0x08048c5a <+54>:    je     0x8048c61 <phase_2+61>
   0x08048c5c <+56>:    call   0x8049375 <explode_bomb>
   0x08048c61 <+61>:    add    $0x4,%ebx
   0x08048c64 <+64>:    cmp    %esi,%ebx
   0x08048c66 <+66>:    jne    0x8048c52 <phase_2+46>
   0x08048c68 <+68>:    jmp    0x8048c74 <phase_2+80>
   0x08048c6a <+70>:    lea    0x20(%esp),%ebx
   0x08048c6e <+74>:    lea    0x30(%esp),%esi
   0x08048c72 <+78>:    jmp    0x8048c52 <phase_2+46>
   0x08048c74 <+80>:    add    $0x34,%esp
   0x08048c77 <+83>:    pop    %ebx
   0x08048c78 <+84>:    pop    %esi
   0x08048c79 <+85>:    ret
```

Other than that i am confused and am having a hard time following what it does to check the six numbers to unlock the phase. Any expertise would be greatly appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

> I think this compares if the first number and first input are equal

I don't understand what you are trying to say there. What is `first number`?

Anyway, `cmpl $0x0,0x18(%esp)` clearly checks that the first input is zero, and similarly `cmpl $0x1,0x1c(%esp)` checks that the second is one.

Afterwards you have a loop that tests all subsequent numbers. The relevant code is:

```
0x08048c52 <+46>:    mov    -0x8(%ebx),%eax
0x08048c55 <+49>:    add    -0x4(%ebx),%eax
0x08048c58 <+52>:    cmp    %eax,(%ebx)
```

`ebx` is holding a pointer to the current array item, as such `-0x4(%ebx)` is the previous element and `-0x8(%ebx)` is the one before that. Thus, it's not hard to see that it's basically doing `if (array[i-2] + array[i-1] != array[i]) explode_bomb();`.

The formula should look familiar to you, it's a well known sequence. But even without recognizing it, given the first two numbers it's a simple task to figure out the rest.